# Controller and Service Methods or Just Controller Alone

Tags: spring

I come across the URL - https://dzone.com/articles/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-kubernetes-sprin where both the controller and the service methods are exposed as REST API's

The confusion comes and it araises the question whether we need to expose controller methods as REST APIs or Service methods are APIS

if we made both of them as REST APIs then when we call a controller methods - 2 HTTP request might be sent and will cause performance issue.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The example that you're looking at is Feign, it is a declarative webservice client to make webservice calls easier between multiple microservices. Feign comes with GetMapping because its designed to work with other microservices.

In General, Controllers will have RequestMapping and handle the routing and service will do the work of running your business logic.

If we configure 2 RequestMapping it doesn't mean 2 HTTP calls will be made, only the ones with right url will be invoked and the other one will be a simple spring bean.